# C function doesn't modify passed array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Hi I need help with my C assignment. I need to modify a dynamic 2d array, so I pass a pointer to it to function, unfortunately it seems to not modify it but only copy it and leave it untouched, I have tried everything, can someone help please?

```
int getUniqueRelMembersCount(universe_t u, relation_t rel, char **members)
{
    int memberCount = 0;

    //count and dynamically populate passed 2d array with unique members of rel

    return memberCount;
}
```

How I call the function:

```
char **members = malloc(sizeof(members));
int len = getUniqueRelMembersCount(universe, relations.relations[0], members);
printf("%d\n", len);
printf("%s", members[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
     free(members[i]);
}

free(members);
```

output:

> 3

> Segmentation fault

EDIT:
Ok, I tried to make a demo using your answer and I am still confused:

```
int populate(char ***members)
{
    *members = malloc(sizeof(*members));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        char string[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
        *members = realloc(*members, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        *members[i] = malloc(strlen(string) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(*members[i], string);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    char **members;
    populate(&members);
    printf("%s\n", members[0]);
    printf("%s\n", members[1]);
    printf("%s\n", members[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

Hello

đOu

(null)

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: The function modifies its `members` variable, but nothing modifies `main`'s `members` variable.

Comment: `char **members = malloc(sizeof(members));` should probably be `char **members = malloc(sizeof(*members) * numberOfMembers);`

Comment: The code in the question is changing frenetically.  The OP has deleted the body of the `getUniqueRelMembersCount()` function several times.

Answer (score 1):

It does modify the array. It might even free it. That's not the problem.

The problem is it also changes the pointer (`members = realloc(...)`), but you don't propagate this change to the caller. Despite having the same name, the variable named `members` in your function and the variable named `members` in the caller are different variables. After your `realloc`, the `members` variable in `main` might no longer be valid.

Simplified demo:

```c
void f(int members) {
   printf("%d\n", members);   // 2
   members = 3;
   printf("%d\n", members);   // 3
}

int main(void) {
   int members = 2;
   printf("%d\n", members);   // 2
   f(members);
   printf("%d\n", members);   // 2
   return 0;
}
```

You could return the modified value. In this case, it's better to pass a pointer to the variable.

```c
int f(int *membersPtr) {
   printf("%d\n", *membersPtr);   // 2
   *membersPtr = 3;
   printf("%d\n", *membersPtr);   // 3
}

int main(void) {
   int members = 2;
   printf("%d\n", members);   // 2
   f(&members);
   printf("%d\n", members);   // 3
   return 0;
}
```

In your full program, a pointer to the variable would have type `char***`.

Answer (score -2):

Your following code shouldn't work:

```
char **members = malloc(sizeof(members));
int len = getUniqueRelMembersCount(universe, relations.relations[0], members);
```

because:

1. you cannot use 'member' value to initialize 'member';
2. malloc returns signle pointer, but not double pointer.

Try this:

```
int members_count = 10;
char *members = malloc(members_count);
int len = getUniqueRelMembersCount(universe, relations.relations[0], &members);
```

Comment: Should be `char **members = malloc(sizeof(*members) * initial_len);`

Comment: Re "*you cannot use 'member' value to initialize 'member';*" False.  `sizeof(members)` is available at compile time. It's not correct, but not for the reason you gave. /// Re "*malloc returns signle pointer, but not double pointer.*", Nonesense. malloc can indeed return a pointer to an array of pointers.

Comment: In fact it probably should be `char **members;` without a malloc; then pass `&members` instead of `members` as argument to the populating function; and do all malloc in the function.

Comment: Re "*In fact it probably should be char **members; without a malloc*", Indeed. Since `initial_len` is 0, no reason not to simply pass `NULL`. `realloc` happily takes `NULL` for its first parameter. That's what I do in such cases. (I was just keeping it simple above.)